# How to run vagrant provision on every up?

Tags: vagrant

I need to run vagrant provision on every `vagrant up`, is it possible? For example, this provision is run only on first `vagrant up`:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false,  path: "provision.sh"
```

What should I specify to run it always on `vagrant up`?

Comment: // , The docs for this are here: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/basic_usage.html#run-once-or-always

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From vagrant 1.6, this [issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2421) has been fixed/addressed so you can specify if you want to run a specific provision on each up you can add `:run => 'always'` to your provisioning line as:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :run => 'always', :path => "provision.sh", :privileged => false
```

the default value is `once`